# How to cast a child model object to its base model in django-polymorphic?

Tags: django

I have `MyBaseModel(PolymorphicModel)` and `MyChildModel(MyBaseModel)`. I retrieve instances of MyChildModel from DB and want to cast the to MyBaseModel in order to pass them to a generic serialisation function (I want them to be serialised as MyBaseModel).

Is this possible?

I tried `MyBaseModel(my_child_model_instance)`, but it produces new instance instead of casting existing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What might work is casting the class directly:
`my_child_model_instance.__class__ = MyBaseModel`

Otherwise, with some performance loss, the django polymorphic docs mention:

> If you insert .non_polymorphic() anywhere into the query chain, then
>   django_polymorphic will simply leave out the final step of retrieving
>   the real objects, and the manager/queryset will return objects of the
>   type of the base class you used for the query, like vanilla Django
>   would (ModelA in this example).

So, `casted = MyBaseModel.objects.non_polymorphic().get(id=my_child_model_instance.id)` will give you a MyBaseModel version of the object.

Comment: In addition to ```my_child_model_instance.__class__ = MyBaseModel``` I had to do ```my_child_model_instance.polymorphic_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(my_child_model_instance, for_concrete_model=False)```

Comment: If I have the opposite: a `MyBaseModel` (let's call it `mbb`) and I want to create a new `MyChildModel` that is linked with `mbb` how would you do?